# How can I put the first activity on pause when switching from the first activity to the second one and not destroy first activity?

Tags: android

I have the **first activity** and a button on it , when I click the button , I go to the **second activity**. And when I moved / am on the second activity I would like the first activity not to be destroyed but to pause(FirstActivity.Pause). Tell me if there are ways to implement this ?

I want to implement this so that the data from the first activity is not deleted.

Thanks!

Comment: That's actually what's supposed to happen. Can you please share the code where you call start activity?

Comment: Don't call `finish()` after `startActivity()`? Although there is no guarantee that FirstActivity won't be recreated, in fact, it WILL be, when you return to SecondActivity after a process death (low memory condition).  That is just how Activities and Android work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity is supposed to pause.
 You should add this line of code to your on create method:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class));
}
});
```

Your Main activity is going to be paused whilst you are on your secondaryActivity.

Answer (score 0):

its the defualt behavior to pause first activty you didn't call finish() on it .
  your Intent should be like this 
`Intent i= new Intent(context, secondActivity.class);
  startActivity(i);`

please share your code to find issue .